# How to show universal id of notes documents in a notes view?

Tags: lotus-notes, hcl-notes

Question is simple that I wanna show Universal Id of each document in a HCL Notes view. I have tried

UniversalId and
UNID

but none of them worked. I mean that column is empty for all documents. I'm referring to the document Id which you can see in the last tab of the Property box in Notes client. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @Text(@DocumentUniqueID). Read more at https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_DOCUMENTUNIQUEID.html

Comment: It works. 

Bundle of thanks :)